# Reverse the combustion engine

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

All you know what a combustion engine is doing: Transform chemical energy into kinetic energy.

What about the opposite? I know when I park a car at a slope and lose the breaks it will drive backwards and downwards. And will not produce petrol because of that :)

But where in the process is that critical point, respectively why will it not produce petrol in detail? 
Are there machines that can do such a process?

Comment: Consider an endothermic chemical reaction, *ie.* one that needs heat to be made. Once equilibrium is reached, you could heat the reaction medium using friction, which would start the reaction again: you've transformed mater using kinetic energy!

Comment: Mh, I guess that's right. Is there already an eample for such a thing? When I think on transforming kinetic energy into a different one only wind and fluid generators come up into my mind.

Comment: You could also use a dynamo to perform and electrolysis!

Comment: Dynamo is a good example! :) How does electrolysis fit as an example?

Comment: I meant /perform an electrolysis/: one can transform mechanical energy into electric energy using a dynamo; then, he could use this electric energy to produce chemical energy through an electrolysis.

Comment: Right, thanks! How do I close the question/accept your comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ways to do the opposite process.

One way would be using an endothermic chemical reaction. Once equilibrium is reached, you could use friction to heat the reaction medium (simply by rubbing the beaker). Then, since the reaction is endothermic, it would start again. This would convert mechanical energy into chemical energy.

Another way would be to perform an electrolysis thanks to a dynamo. The dynamo would convert mechanical energy into electric energy, which would then be converted into chemical energy through an electrolysis.